# script not running on Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and just learning about the while, as well as if function. So I have an idea in mind is to create a blackjack game using those commands. I want to test out if my scripts running probably and heading the right way that I was looking for or not by hit run (there was no error) in which there's no script executed. Would someone mind telling me what I did wrong that could make the script not executable? Sorry for my terrible English, I'm not a native speaker.

```
import random
first_card = random.randint(1, 10)
second_card = random.randint(1, 10)
card_onhand = first_card + second_card
card_chance = 0
card_limit = 3
number_limit = 21
random_card = random.randint(1, 10)
while card_chance < card_limit and card_onhand > 15:
    condition = input("would you like to play ?")
    if condition.lower() == "yes":
        print(f"your current card numbers are: {card_onhand}")
    else:
        print("Have a nice day!")
    user_decision = input("Hit or Stand?")
    card_chance += 1
    if user_decision.lower() == "Hit":
        card_number1 = card_onhand + random_card
        print(card_number1)
        user_decision1 = input("would you like to hit or stand?")
        if user_decision1.lower() == "stand" and card_number1 <= number_limit:
            print(card_number1)
        elif user_decision.lower() == "hit":
            card_number2 = card_number1 + random_card
            print(card_number2)
            user_decision2 = input("would you like to hit or stand?")
            if user_decision2.lower() == "stand" and card_number2 <= number_limit:
                print(card_number2)
            elif user_decision.lower() == "hit":
                card_number3 = card_number2 + random_card
                print(card_number3)
                if card_number3 > number_limit:
                    print("you lose!")
                else:
                    print("card_number3")
        else:
            print("you over!")
    print(f"your current number is {card_onhand}")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps I'm not understanding, but how did you execute it? Did you run `python script.py` or are you doing something differently?

Comment: Hi , i just hit shift + f10 , which is what the tutorial on youtube told me. Work for me everytime except this time ...

Comment: Can you elaborate on "no script executed"? Do you just mean you see nothing printed out in the console? This could be because `card_onhand` is smaller than `15` from the beginning since it is the sum of 2 random numbers ranging from 1 to 10 (so card_onhand could be from 2->14 and the stuff inside the `while loop` never runs). Try reducing the minimum requirement of 'card_onhand' or make the 2 random numbers `first_card` and `second_card` have a higher lower bound. Sorry not sure what the rules of BlackJack are but that could be the problem here.

Comment: thank you so much! I have figured it out. I forgot that card on hand could range between 2->14 in which i forgot to set condition for it so it won't show anything.